# Integrate Keycloak with FastAPI

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi, openid-connect

I have an app that is written with FastAPI and SvelteKit, both these is running in separate containers, the current solution is Svelte sends the username and password to the FastAPI server, the FastAPI server then returns a signed JWT to svelte which is used to authenticate with FastAPI.

Heres the login flow
Svelte -> username + password -> FastAPI

FastAPI -> JWT -> Svelte(stored in cookie)

Here's what happens when a request is made
Svelte(Authorization: Bearer) -> FastAPI

I want to get rid of my own username and password and use KeyCloak for my authentication. I'm super new to OAuth so I have no idea what I'm supposed to do or even what terms to search.

Here's what I understand I want:
Svelte(goto "/login") -> redirects to keycloak -> login and get a token (somehow get the token to FastAPI so I can sign my own token and send it to svelte)

And when I make a request
Svelte -> FastAPI Token -> FastAPI

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884938/generate-jwt-token-in-keycloak-and-get-public-key-to-verify-the-jwt-token-on-a-t ?

Comment: @MatsLindh Interesting but I'm still a bit confused, what you are saying is that I should login from the frontend get the token then store. and when I make a request FastAPI shoud be the one verifying the token?

Comment: Yes, that's how the exchange usually happens with JWTs - keycloak signes the token, you then verify that the token was properly signed in your backend server. FastAPI will have to verify the token in either case; that way you trust the token signed på keycloak (and if you need to, you can verify with keycloak from FastAPI that the token is still valid and hasn't been revoked/user deactivated/etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I saw something about the tokens expiring every 5 mins so do I have to constantly keep refreshing the token?

Comment: Yes, if you're going with a JWT that you don't explicitly verify that the user is still valid for on the FastAPI side, then those five minutes is the maximum time that will elapse before the user is no longer logged in.

Answer (score 8):

I crafted some [Python code](https://github.com/ilyesAj/keycloak-fastAPI-integration/tree/main) for fastAPI with keycloak integration, it may be helpful to share it.

**Declare auth functions**

```py
#/auth.py
from fastapi.security import OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID # pip require python-keycloak
from config import settings
from fastapi import Security, HTTPException, status,Depends
from pydantic import Json
from models import User

# This is used for fastapi docs authentification
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl=settings.authorization_url, # https://sso.example.com/auth/
    tokenUrl=settings.token_url, # https://sso.example.com/auth/realms/example-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
)

# This actually does the auth checks
# client_secret_key is not mandatory if the client is public on keycloak
keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url=settings.server_url, # https://sso.example.com/auth/
    client_id=settings.client_id, # backend-client-id
    realm_name=settings.realm, # example-realm
    client_secret_key=settings.client_secret, # your backend client secret
    verify=True
)

async def get_idp_public_key():
    return (
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        f"{keycloak_openid.public_key()}"
        "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
    )

# Get the payload/token from keycloak
async def get_payload(token: str = Security(oauth2_scheme)) -> dict:
    try:
        return keycloak_openid.decode_token(
            token,
            key= await get_idp_public_key(),
            options={
                "verify_signature": True,
                "verify_aud": False,
                "exp": True
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail=str(e), # "Invalid authentication credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    
# Get user infos from the payload
async def get_user_info(payload: dict = Depends(get_payload)) -> User:
    try:
        return User(
            id=payload.get("sub"),
            username=payload.get("preferred_username"),
            email=payload.get("email"),
            first_name=payload.get("given_name"),
            last_name=payload.get("family_name"),
            realm_roles=payload.get("realm_access", {}).get("roles", []),
            client_roles=payload.get("realm_access", {}).get("roles", [])
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail=str(e), # "Invalid authentication credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
```

**Define your models , you can use what ever model you need :**

```py
#/models.py
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr

class User(BaseModel):
    id: str
    username: str
    email: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    realm_roles: list
    client_roles: list

class authConfiguration(BaseModel):
        server_url: str
        realm: str
        client_id: str
        client_secret: str
        authorization_url: str
        token_url: str
```

**Define your config:**

```py
#/config.py
from models import authConfiguration


settings = authConfiguration(
    server_url="http://localhost:8080/",
    realm="roc",
    client_id="rns:roc:portal",
    client_secret="",
    authorization_url="http://localhost:8080/realms/roc/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    token_url="http://localhost:8080/realms/roc/protocol/openid-connect/token",
)
```

**and finally define your routes and secure them:**

```
#/main.py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends
from models import User
from auth import get_user_info

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@app.get("/secure")
async def root(user: User = Depends(get_user_info)):
    return {"message": f"Hello {user.username} you have the following service: {user.realm_roles}"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('main:app', host="127.0.0.1", port=8081)
```

On the keycloak side create a realm and within this real create a client. Create a test user to use it for authentification and that's it!

**References:**

- https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9066
- https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/

Comment: Great code! It seems that one must input `rns:roc:portal` as a `client_id` in order to trigger the connection through Keycloak. Would there be a way to not have to input this and get to the Keycloak login when clicking on Authorize?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to add Keycloak authentication to an app is [oauth2-proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/). oauth2-proxy stands in front of your application like a reverse proxy and it'll handle all the OAuth2 bits for you. oauth2-proxy will then generate the sign-in URL to Keycloak (`/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`) with the appropriate parameters to start an OAuth2 sign in process and set it to redirect back to the application page, Keycloak will display sign-in page, then after the user completed their sign in, it'll redirect back to the application, at which point oauth2-proxy will check the JWT token are valid, set a cookie, and then pass along the username, access token, and ID token to the server as HTTP headers to the proxied request.

When using a oauth2-proxy kind of approach, neither your Svelte frontend app or FastAPI app needs to know anything about OIDC/OAuth2, they don't even need access to the client secret, which reduces the chance of your application leaking those secrets. The application may need to be able to decode a JWT token to read Access token and ID token (which contains the auth claims), but if all you need is just a Keycloak validated username/email, then your FastAPI app can just read the HTTP headers with `Header()` to get the username. Decoding JWT without signature verification (because we assume that oauth2-proxy already validated the signature) is pretty simple to implement with just standard library, it's basically just a couple string manipulation, base64, and json parsing.

Alternatively, you can implement OAuth2 flow directly in your application. Direct integration may be necessary if the application needs to do things that are more complicated than just basic authentication and authorisation with the JWT tokens or if you want finer control over the auth process. Keycloak supports OAuth2 via OIDC, so you can use any OIDC library like [pyoidc](https://pyoidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or with a Keycloak specific integration like [fastapi-keycloak-middleware](https://fastapi-keycloak-middleware.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Implementing OAuth2 without OIDC is also possible but it will be much more involved. Keycloak, OIDC, and OAuth2 all has a lot of configuration involved to support various different use cases and security requirements, you'll need to look into these configurations in more detail to figure out which suits your requirement.

Implementing all this without using an OIDC and/or OAuth2 libraries is possible, but I wouldn't really recommend them. You'll just end up reading a lot of boring OAuth2 and OIDC specs.

Answer (score -1):

its me again, here's a conclusion for those who come across this thread in the future. I've decided to go with the official keycloak.js connector for my app and the keycloak [python lib](https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/) to verify the token on the backend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).