# How to connect FastAPI, Jinja2 and Keycloak?

Tags: python, jinja2, keycloak, fastapi

I work for a company and I have a Python FastAPI project. This is something like a multi-page website, where each endpoint is a page of the site. This was done using Jinja2 - TemplateResponse(). I know that this is not the best solution for similar projects, such as Flask or Django, but there is no way to change it.

I need to hide content using Keycloak authentication. I took the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77186511/21439459

Made same endpoint:

```
@app.get("/secure")
async def root(user: User = Depends(get_user_info)):
    return {"message": f"Hello {user.username} you have the following service: {user.realm_roles}"}
```

When I run the page I get (Not authenticated):

[image: Not authenticated picture]

I don't understand how a user can authenticate. I expected a redirect to the Keycloak page like in other frameworks.
Interesting point when running /docs

[image: auth picture]

Here, after entering the data, a correct redirect to Keycloak occurs and after entering the login/password, I can receive a response from the secure endpoint.

[image: picture]

I need help with a redirect when opening my website. I don't understand how to repeat authentication from the documentation.

I tried the fastapi_keycloak library, but as I understand it, it does not work with the company's version of keycloak.

I tried fastapi-keycloak-middleware, but I also received a 401 error and did not understand how to authenticate users.

Comment: In your `get_user_info` function - if there isn't a user available, you can issue a redirect to keycloak as you find necessary (call `RedirectResponse(url='https://keycloakinstance/path'`)

Comment: @MatsLindh I think I need something from python-keycloak library ( https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/ ) like keycloak_openid.auth_url() but I don't understand how to add it to project